# Compare multiple tsv files for match columns

Tags: bash, csv, ubuntu, compare

I have 4466 .tsv files with this structure:
[file_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94zzm.png)

I want to compare the 4466 files to see how many IDs (the first column) matches.
I only found bash commands with two files with "comm". Could you tell me how I could do that?

Thank you

Comment: Is "tsv" like "csv", but with a tab as column separator?

Comment: What do you mean by _how many IDs **matches**_? This sentence does not make sense to me.

Comment: Please post a code block (`\`\`\``) with an example input instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Do you wish to compare EVERY file to ALL others ? It will be an immense amount of comparisons. How do you plan to store this information, and what would you do in case of  a match (or mismatch). You should put in code tags what you  HAVE, what you EXPECT and what you have TRIED.  Currently your question is fairly vague.

Comment: @MyICQ, if OP wants the intersection of IDs for every file (as I believe they do) we can do this with exactly N comparisons, storing the results in a file that will remain a constant (relatively small) size, or shrink.

Comment: @ZachYoung, correct, but you could also read as "IDs that are shared between file fileA and fileB". Example: A and B share IDs [1,4,9]  - A and C share [2,13] - B and C share [13] etc etc.  Would that not give many more comparisons ?

Answer (score 1):

I read your question as:

> Amongst all TSV files, which column IDs are found in **every** file?

If that's true, we want the *intersection* of all the sets of column IDs from all files. We can use the join command to get the intersection of any two files, and we can use the algebraic properites of an intersection to effectively join all files.

Consider the intersection of ID for these three files:

```
file1.tsv   file2.tsv   file3.tsv
---------   ---------   ---------
ID          ID          ID       
1           1           2        
2           3           3        
3
```

"3" is the only ID shared between all three.  We can only join two files together at a time, so we need some way to effectively get, `join (join file1.tsv file2.tsv) file3.tsv`.  Fortunately for us intersections are [*idempotent* and *associative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Algebraic_properties), so we can apply join iteratively in a loop over all the files, like so:

```bash
# "Prime" the common file
cp file1.tsv common.tsv

for TSV in file*.tsv; do
    join "$TSV" common.tsv > myTmp
    mv myTmp common.tsv

    echo "After joining $TSV, common IDs are:"
    cat common.tsv
done
```

When I run that it prints the following:

```
After joining file1.tsv, common IDs are:
ID
1
2
3
After joining file2.tsv, common IDs are:
ID
1
3
After joining file3.tsv, common IDs are:
ID
3
```

1. The first iteration joins file1 with itself (because we primed common with file1); this is where we intersection to be idempotent
2. The second iteration joins in file2, cutting out ID "2"
3. The third iteration joins in file3, cutting ID down to just "3"

Technically, join considers the string "ID" to be one of the things to evaluate... it doesn't know what a header line is, or an what an ID is... it just knows to look in some number of *fields* for common values.  In that example we didn't specify a field so it defaulted to the first field, and it always found "ID" and it always found "3".

For your files, we need to tell join to:

- separate on a tab character, with -t <TAB-CHAR>
- only output the join field (which, by default, is the first field), with -o 0

Here's my full implementation:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
TAB="$(printf '\t')"

# myJoin joins tsvX with the previously-joined common on 
# the first field of both files; saving the the first field
# of the joined output back into common
myJoin() {
    tsvX="$1"

    join -t "$TAB" -o 0 common.tsv "$tsvX" > myTmp.tsv
    mv myTmp.tsv common.tsv
}

# "Prime" common
cp input1.tsv common.tsv

for TSV in input*.tsv; do
    myJoin "$TSV"
done

echo "The common IDs are:"
tail -n -1 common.tsv
```

For an explanation of why `"$(printf '\t')"`, check out the following for POSIX compliance:

- https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC3003
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468048/366399

Answer (score 0):

The question sounds quite vague. So, assuming that you want to extract IDs that *all* 4466 files have *in common*, i.e. IDs such that each of them occurs at least *once* in *all* of the `*.tsv` files, you can do this (e.g.) in pure Bash using associative arrays and calculating “set intersections” on them.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# removes all IDs from array $1 that do not occur in array $2.
intersect_ids() {
  local -n acc="$1"
  local -rn operand="$2"
  local id
  for id in "${!acc[@]}"; do
    ((operand["$id"])) || unset "acc['${id}']"
  done
}

# prints IDs that occur in all files called *.tsv in directory $1.
get_ids_intersection() (
  shopt -s nullglob
  local -ar files=("${1}/"*.tsv)
  local -Ai common_ids next_ids
  local file id _
  if ((${#files[@]})); then
    while read -r id _; do ((++common_ids["$id"])); done < "${files[0]}"
    for file in "${files[@]:1}"; do
      while read -r id _; do ((++next_ids["$id"])); done < "$file"
      intersect_ids common_ids next_ids
      next_ids=()
    done
  fi
  for id in "${!common_ids[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$id"; done
)

get_ids_intersection /directory/where/tsv/files/are
```